# Package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-166-generic is missing in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kernel, chef

I have a chef script that installs `linux-image-extra` for whatever the given kernel is on the system by doing `apt-get -y install linux-image-extra-uname -r`, but today it's started to fail saying that `linux-image-extra-3.13.0-166-generic` does not exist.

I check myself and sure enough, there are a million `linux-image-extra packages`, except for `3.13.0-166`.

Is this a temporary problem? Should I find a way to use an older kernel? Why is that package missing?

Comment: We've noticed the same problem, have filed a [bug report on launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pkg-website/+bug/1819962).

Comment: Thanks for confirming that I'm not crazy, David. We were actually able to remove that dependency from our build process but I'm glad that an issue is filed.